# VBA compare 2 values in different worksheets if they match copy specific data from row to another row

Tags: vba

I am struggling with a VBA problem.
I have 2 worksheets in the same workbook
"Rota" and "sheet3"
column "a" in Rota has a list of names columns "B"-"AQ" are dates
Column "a" in sheet3 has a list of names columns "B"-"AQ" are dates
Against each name in sheet3 there are cells with values "X1" "No" "Yes"
I need to compare the names and if they match, look in the row matching the name in sheet3 and copy only the X1 values into the correct date cells for the matched name in Rota.

I have added a picture to demonstrate the 2 sheets, you will notice that there are multiples of the same date, that is because the dates are split into shifts so there will be up to three shifts for each date so the dates would have to be read Sequentially from sheet three and matched in sequence to Rota. The dates will always appear in the same sequence in each sheet but not in the same corresponding cells, example rota rota s6 and sheets3 s6.

this has been driving mad trying to work out the best way of doing this

[image: Example]
Hopefully my explanation is good enough for someone to have a crack at this

Edit: Code from comment

```
Dim i As Long 
Dim j As Long 
Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("availability").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("allocation").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow 
For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow 
If Worksheets("availability").Cells(j, 1).Value = "Paul Wing" = Worksheets("allocation").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Paul Wing" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
```

Comment: Sounds easy enough! Tell me if this breakdown of your problem is correct: **1.** get string from sheet1; **2.** if string is found in sheet2 -> **3.** copy specific values from same row to sheet1; **4.** back to step 1 with next string

Comment: yes that sounds correct the X1 values must be placed under the same date values in sheet1 (Rota) as they appear under in sheet3

Comment: I have spent hours searching for an answer to this after your very helpful comments, trouble is, being a total beginner at this I find the code examples I find to be completely incomprehensible,  very few people seem to comment their code to enable amateurs like me to actually understand what is going on and without this it is akin to trying to decipher ancient Aramaic . I am pretty sure this code is going to help me on my way if I could just have a detailed explanation of what it is doing.

Comment: Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("availability").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("allocation").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
        For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
            If Worksheets("availability").Cells(j, 1).Value = "Paul Wing" = Worksheets("allocation").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Paul Wing" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value

Comment: Arrrrrgggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh it won't let me post the code. I give up what is the bloody point you try to learn something and ask other more knowledgeable people and all you get told is to go look it up for yourself. Next time someone asks me how to change an oil pump on a V8 I won't bother to help them out in anyway I can, passing on my knowledge and enriching both myself and them, I will just tell them to go look it up. Sorry for the rant but I find this very frustrating there is a wealth of VBA stuff out and if people would just comment their code it would really help.

Comment: And of course that would mean that I would not be asking what is I am sure ( to the experts) really annoyingly simple questions. It took me years to train to be an engineer as I am sure it took years for a programmer to learn his or her trade it would just be nice if it could be shared a little more readily.........................Rant over and thanks for all the help

Comment: You can always post your code in your question on top, there is a wonderful code formating function implemented, just waiting for you to use it. The comments are indeed not the place for code. And as for the help: This page is not meant to be a "how to start coding" guide. [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/) is one of many pages where you can start learning VBA. SO on the other hand will give you specific answers to [specific questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Update your question accordingly for further help.

Answer (score 1):

These are the (main) steps you need for your task:

- find value in worksheet
- copy value into string
- loop through cells/range
- copy data between worksheets

Use the search engine of your choice and add *vba excel* in front of these steps. You will find plenty of example code that will get you started.

Create minimal example sheets and test your code there before applying it to the actual workbook. If you get stuck with any of those tasks, feel free to ask more question which include the specific code that you need help with.

Keep in mind that SO is not a place to ask questions like "how to start on this", but rather about specific question to specific code.